# Add class to empty elements only

Tags: jquery

The problem is that I have multiple instances of `.Prodotto` but I would like to add the class only to the empty `.Prodotto`. How can I specify only the empty '.Prodotto' ? My jQuery attempt is this one:

```
if ($('.Prodotto').is(':empty')){
  $('.Prodotto').addClass('empty-content');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:empty` selector directly and remove the `if` statement, like this:

```
$('.Prodotto:empty').addClass('empty-content');
```

Comment: in 11 minutes I will accept your answer .. it doesn't let me now.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I think what you're trying to do is

```
$('.Prodotto:empty').addClass('empty-content');
```

But when you say the "Current .Prodotto", it implies there is something else in your code which makes it the "current" one, like having clicked on it, and if so your code is similar to your existing, except using `this`

```
$('.Prodotto').on('click',function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is(':empty')){
        $this.addClass('empty-content');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
$('.Prodotto').filter(':empty').addClass('empty-content');
```

Or even shorter:

```
$('.Prodotto:empty').addClass('empty-content');
```

In your code you're first testing if there are any empty elements with the class *Prodotto*, but then you query *Prodotto* a second time and apply the new class to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague, if you give a bit more details, but I assume that you have a click event somewhere?
If that is the case, assuming you have something like:

```
    $("body").on("click", ".Prodotto", function(){ 
    if($(this).is(":empty")){ 
            $(this).addClass("empty-content");
    }
    });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes, I formulated my question a bit bad ... putting "current" in the description, maybe I should remove it.. there is no clicking event.